# Least data-heavy way to retrieve 5 closest users in Firebase/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, location, distance

Let's imagine I have a Firebase setup like this, except with 10,000 users:

```
"users" : {
    "user 1" : {
      "latitude": 1234567,
      "Longitude": 7654321,
      "name": "Name 1"
    },
    "user 2" : {
      "latitude": 1234567,
      "longitude": 7654321,
      "name": "Name 2"
    },
    "user 3" : {
      "latitude": 1234567,
      "Longitude": 7654321,
      "name": "Name 3"
    },
    "user 4" : {
      "latitude": 1234567,
      "Longitude": 7654321,
      "name": "Name 4"
    },
  }
```

What would be the least data-intensive way to generate a list of the 5 users closest to me?  Very new to this, so the only solutions I can think of would require querying all 10,000 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very new to this subject, therefore I can only point you in the right direction. Essentially the way you're storing user location is not optimal. The best way to do it is to use [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) a newish addition to the Firebase service. How it works is you should have a large location object and you store the geolocation of those users using that users key. Here's an example.

```
   {
     Locations: {
        -KH35xPkJmX0UTSG8DuM : {
           "g" : "randomID",
           "l" : {
                  "0" : "latitude",
                  "1" : "longitude"
                 }
        }
     }
    }

   {
     Users: {
       -KH35xPkJmX0UTSG8DuM : {
         "username" : "Joe Sloan"
       }
     }
   }
```

Your locations object will have 10,000 users keys and geoLocations. the value of "g" and "l" object are set when you use

```
   geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 37.7853889, longitude: -122.4056973), forKey: "firebase-hq")
```

Google has optimized the query for users within a similar location.

```
    let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.7832889, longitude: -122.4056973)
    // Query locations at [37.7832889, -122.4056973] with a radius of 600 meters
    var circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 0.6)
```

The circleQuery variable should contain a Firebase dictionary of the closest users. As I said I haven't had a chance to really delve deeper but this should give you a start.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.  I considered this, but couldn't determine whether Geofire would work with Swift, as I'd only seen support for it in other languages.  Do you know if there are any Swift Geofire resources out there?

Comment: The GeoFire Framework is written in Objective-C, however if you head over to the GeoFire github they've provided documentation for swift! Firebase is really good about providing swift documentation.  The code snippets I posted above are all in swift and directly from the github page. The recommended way to add GeoFire in your app is through CoacoaPods!